# Newline all-in-one python string

Tags: python, html, django, string

I have:

```
...
post_str = "Please input the following information... \nDescription: \n Last Name:"
context = {
     'post_str':post_str,
      ...
}
return render_to_response('contact/contact.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

It prints like so,

`Please input the following information... Description: Last Name:`.

But I'd like it to print:

```
Please input the following information...
Description:
Last Name:
```

I thought I was using it correctly. How do I get a the newline to successfully produce what I need?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Show actual code (i.e., how are you printing it?).

Comment: I guess I should state I'm using Django/Python. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newlines don't do anything in HTML. Use `<br />` instead.